# Copy and paste error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Is there something wrong with my formula? I'm trying to use a formula to bring me to `gotoreference(I.e f5)` the cell to verify that cells are indeed right before proceeding or either msgbox prompting to proceed or that the workbook/worksheet cannot be found. Also sometimes the person leaves blank because it is quarterly data, I would like it to autoextract latest data (farthest) column.

I've two workbooks: one is my current workbook (Currentworkbook.xlsx) that I'm running the macro on. The other is Jedata.xlsx of 'Mysheettab' and few other workbooks not listed here, will be feeding information into Currentworkbook.xlsx of 'Sheet1'.

```
Option explicit

Sub Macro3()
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook("Jedata")
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mysheettab")

On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Data sheet not found"
Else

Activate.Windows ("wb")
Sheets("ws").Select
Application.Goto Reference:=Range("AG28:AG32").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Currentworkbook").Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("H10:H14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see lot of errors in your code.

First things first. You avoid the use of `.Activate/.Select`. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Next regarding `Activate.Windows ("wb")`. Anything between the `"` will be considered as a string. I think you wanted to try

```
wb.Activate
```

But like I mentioned, you should avoid the use of `.Activate/.Select`. Your code can be written as (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim wb As Workbook, thiswb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, thisws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set thiswb = thisowrkbook
    Set thisws = thiswb.ActiveSheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("Jedata")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mysheettab")

    ws.Range("AG28:AG32").Copy thisws.Range("H10")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description  
End Sub
```